# How can we get the program counter address using LLVM compiler?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-gcc, llvm-3.0

I am trying to write an LLVM pass which would pass the program counter as an argument. However, I am not sure as to which command or how exactly one can get the program counter address using the llvm classes.

Comment: LLVM passes run during compile time, before it's known whether there even is a program counter. There might also be zero or many; zero if the code being considered won't ever be run (as is common for static analysis tools), many in multithreaded situations. What is your deeper problem — what motivates you to want the PC?

Comment: I am trying to use a tool built on LLVM to inject soft errors/faults into random instructions, however, I wish to extend this tool to also display the PC adddress of the instruction into which the fault is being injected

Comment: I see, what you want is the address of an instruction. That's much clearer, and might be possible in a MachinePass, but won't be possible in a Pass, because plain Passes run before code generation and linking, and the linker is whaty assigns addresses. I suggest that you try something different, such as perhaps [injecting some metadata](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#a695a53ce0b9f537880373b4ea1824a6b) that you can spot later in the executable.

Comment: I wish to check the behavior of fault when injected into instruction at a pc address and check gnu v/s llvm implementations for fault injections into that address lead to similar behavior. Could you suggest how I could do the same?

Comment: Well, first off, the address of an instruction doesn't change dependong on the program counter. If an instruction is at address 0x1234567 while the CPU is executing it, it'll also be at 0x1234567 while the CPU is executing something else. So the PC doesn't matter. Second, you can add metadata to an instruction, and some of the metadata survives in the final executable. This is how debug info works. You can mark the modified instrructions using metadata, and then look at the executable and see which instructions are marked, and take the address of those.