# Correlating LLVM IR analysis with final address

Tags: llvm, x86-64, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to design a LLVM IR pass that gets some information from the LLVM IR (specifically: types used in a IR call instruction) and somehow correlate this IR-level analysis with binary-level addresses. For example, I want to know that a `call` instruction (at a certain address in the final binary) is calling a function with a certain type signature.

Some observations:

1. The obvious problem is that the final addresses are not available yet when the IR pass runs.
2. While IR instruction do not map 1:1 to machine instructions, it should be relatively safe to assume that a `call` in IR will map to a `call` in machine code.
3. One could just disassemble the binary, look at the function being called, and get its type. However, this does not work for indirect call instructions (which is why I'm trying to do this in IR).

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273918/how-can-we-get-the-program-counter-address-using-llvm-compiler#comment110151242_62273918), the suggested approach to a similar problem is to "inject[] some metadata that you can spot later in the executable". However, I couldn't find any information about how to make metadata survive in the binary.

Comment: That was me commenting... and if you are an unprincipled hacker like me you might tie the IR calls to the final calls using the debug location (which is a kind of metadata). If you make sure there is a file name, line and column for reach call in IR, this hack should be possible. Cleaner solutions exist, I am sure.

Comment: @arnt: Thank you, it's a great idea. Please consider entering it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: *a call in IR will map to a call in machine code.* - I'd expect that function inlining can happen in the back-end optimizer, after C++ -> LLVM-IR in the front-end.  Perhaps you mean in a debug build, and not counting `__attribute__((always_inline))`?

Comment: @PeterCordes: a better way to express my idea might be *every binary `call` has a corresponding IR `call`*. Does this sound accurate?

Comment: Sounds likely, except maybe for operations that expands to a libgcc helper function call.  (Like uint64_t division on a 32-bit machine, or __builtin_popcount with `-mpopcnt`, etc.) Unless those get expanded before clang generates LLVM-IR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might tie the IR calls to the final calls using the debug location (which is a kind of metadata). If you make sure there is a file name, line and column for each call in IR, this hack should be possible. Cleaner solutions exist, I am sure.